# Значение по умолчанию для аргумента функции javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

Имеется функция, суммирующая все переданные ей аргументы. Все прекрасно работает, но при передаче значения по умолчанию для одного из аргументов, функция не видит это значение и считает без него. Помогите разобраться с этим

```js
function sumWithDefaults(a, b = 100) {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i]
  }
  return result
}

console.log(sumWithDefaults(10));  // выведет 10 вместо 110
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы задали значение по умолчанию не для `arguments[1]`, а именно для переменной `b`. Увы, вещи это далеко не равнозначные.
 Так что поправить Ваш код следует таким образом:

```js
function sumWithDefaults(a, b = 100) {
  let result = a + b;
  for (let i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(sumWithDefaults(10));          // выведет 110
console.log(sumWithDefaults(10, 50));      // выведет 60
console.log(sumWithDefaults(10, 50, 30));  // выведет 90
```

Советую прочитать справку по [параметрам по умолчанию от Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), а также по [объекту arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). Помимо всего прочего там говорится, что

> Объект arguments — это подобный массиву объект, который содержит
>   аргументы, переданные в функцию.

То есть в `arguments` будут храниться **только** и **только** те аргументы, которые Вы явно туда **передали**! Никаких параметров по умолчанию внутри не содержится

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог решить Вам поставленную задачу, а также разобраться в вопросе!
Удачи в Ваших начинаниях!

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснения!

Comment: @Fidel.Marti всегда рады помочь)

Answer (score 2):

в `arguments` хранятся **фактически переданные** параметры.

Так как функция вызывается с одним параметров, в данной коллекции будет всего один элемент.